# How to import hdf5 data with dask in parallel and create a dask dataframe?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-dataframe

I am completely stuck, hence I am looking for kind advice.
My aim is to read out many hdf5 files in parallel, extract the multi-dim arrays inside, and store each array in one row, precisely a cell, of a dask dataframe. I don't opt for a pandas df, because I believe it will be too big.

- It is not possible to read with `read_hdf()` from dask hdf5 files created with h5py.
  What could I do to import thousands of hdf5-files with dask in paralleL and get access to the multi-dim arrays inside?
- I would like to create a dask dataframe, where each 2d-array (extracted from the n-dim arrays inside the hdfs)  is stored in one cell of a dask dataframe.
  Consequently, the number of row corresponds to the number of total arrays found in all files, here 9. I store in one column the arrays.
- In the future I would like to append more columns with other data to this dask dataframe. and I would like to operate on the arrays with another Python library and store the results in other columns of the dask dataframe. The dataframe should contain all the information I extract and manipulate. I would also like to add data from other hdf5 files. Like a minidata base. Is this reasonable?
- I can work in parallel because the arrays are independent of each other.

How would you realise this, please? xarray was suggested to me as well, but I don't know what's the best way.
Earlier I tried to collect all arrays in a multi-dimensional dask array, but the conversion to a dataframe is only possible for ndim=2.

Thank you for your advice. Have a good day.

```py
import numpy as np
import h5py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import dask
print('This is dask version', dask.__version__)


ra=np.ones([10,3199,4000])

print(ra.shape)
file_list=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    #print(i)
    fstr='data_{0}.h5'.format(str(i))
    #print(fstr)
    hf = h5py.File('./'+fstr, 'w')
    hf.create_dataset('dataset_{0}'.format(str(i)), data=ra)
    hf.close()
    file_list.append(fstr)

!ls

print(file_list)

for i,fn in enumerate(file_list):
    dd.read_hdf(fn,key='dataset_{0}'.format(str(i))) #breaks here
```

Comment: xarray was probably suggested as a wholesale replacement for dask.dataframe - you can work with more than two dimensions using xarray with dask arrays as the backend. That seems like a good suggestion and I recommend taking a look at using xarray for manipulating N-D arrays, especially from hdf5 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process the data into dataframes using dask.distributed and then convert the futures to a single dask.dataframe using [`dask.dataframe.from_delayed`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.from_delayed.html).

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd

client = Client()

def preprocess_hdf_file_to_dataframe(filepath):
    # process your data into a dataframe however you want, e.g.
    with xr.open_dataset(filepath) as ds:
        return ds.to_dataframe()

files = ['file1.hdf5', 'file2.hdf5']

futures = client.map(preprocess_hdf_file_to_dataframe, files)
df = dd.from_delayed(futures)
```

That said, this seems like a perfect use case for xarray, which can read HDF5 files and work with dask natively, e.g.

```py
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(files)
```

This dataset is similar to a dask.dataframe, in that it contains references to dask.arrays which are read from the file. But xarray is built to handle N-dimensional arrays natively and can work much more naturally with the HDF5 format.

There are certainly areas where dataframes make more sense than a Dataset or DataArray, though, and converting between them can be tricky with larger-than-memory data, so the first approach is always an option if you want a dataframe.

Comment: Dear Michael, many thanks. I am following your recommendation and looking into xarray and `xr.open_mfdataset`, still some struggles on the way. Maybe I can switch to dataframes, as soon as I reduced my data a bit. Is there a strict rule that a dataframe should only contain in each cell a single value instead of 1d vector with e.g. 1000 values?

Comment: You can do this, but it will be very slow. whenever possible, try to work with continuous arrays of the correct dimensionality. A DataFrame of arrays is a python object (df) containing 2D blocks of optimized cython pointers (the underlying df array) to a very large number of slow python objects (the numpy vectors), each containing 1D optimized cython data. This is far worse than a single xarray python object containing an ND block of optimized cython data.