# Can rechunking using dask may help to load data faster?

Tags: bigdata, dask, python-xarray

I have a single data file as file.h5.gz having 4GB size. I used

```
fZe1 = gzip.open(eDataFN1, 'rb')
fDataIne1 = h5py.File(fZe1, 'r')
```

to load the file. It takes much longer time to load. The file contains keys as         `['nhits', 'rechit_energy', rechit_x, rechit_y', rechit_z', 'target']`.

I heard that dask or xarray may resolve the issue. So I tried to convert as follows and tried to see the number of chunks.

```
nh = da.from_array(fDataIne1['nhits'])
rechitE = da.from_array(fDataIne1['rechit_energy'])
rechitX = da.from_array(fDataIne1['rechit_x'])
rechitY = da.from_array(fDataIne1['rechit_y'])
rechitZ = da.from_array(fDataIne1['rechit_z'])
target  = da.from_array(fDataIne1['target'])
```

If I see anyone of `nh`, `target` etc. I see that

```
              Array         Chunks
     Bytes   4.95 MiB       4.95 MiB
     Shape   (648277,)      (648277,)
Dask graph   1 chunks in 2 graph layers
 Data type   float64 numpy.ndarray
```

Is it possible to rechunk data as (5000,) and save as h5.gz file so that data is loaded much faster? By the way, I have 32GB RAM in my laptop.

Any help is appreciated.

*** I consulted:
[How to import hdf5 data with dask in parallel and create a dask dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398210/how-to-import-hdf5-data-with-dask-in-parallel-and-create-a-dask-dataframe)

[Loading large zipped data-set using dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399866/loading-large-zipped-data-set-using-dask)

Since dask, xarray are new to me and I am novice, I could not figure it out.

Comment: Please check: you say you have a 4GB file, but then you show an array with a single 5MB chunk. 
See also: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#numpy-slicing

Comment: The file size is 4 GB. The file contains keys as mentioned. I tried to see one of the keys which shows 5MiB. I want to know whether re-slicing the data and storing again may help to load data faster. Otherwise, is there any other ways to load data faster?

Comment: So you have thousands of keys?? Making *smaller* chunks will certainly not help you.